# Is it legitimate to compare the accuracy between SVM models?

Tags: regression, svm, logit, accuracy, libsvm

I wish to investigate whether variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ provide any additional explanatory power to variable y, above and beyond some control $X$. I prefer using the support vector machine (SVM) method as (I) $y$ is a binary variable, (II) I want to control for non monotonic effects of $x1$ and $x_2$ on $y$, and (III) I want to make no distributional assumptions (since a logit model would impose more restrictions). I'm using a non linear SVM with the RBF kernel.

Essentially, I'm wondering if it's legit to compare the accuracy of training and test data between an SVM that uses $X$ as input variables on y and another SVM that uses $X$, $x_1$, $x_2$ as input variables on $y$. Are the accuracy scores directly comparable?

Comment: The only distributional assumption that a logit model makes is that y is a binary variable.

Comment: That aside, are accuracy scores of SVM models with nested input variables (i.e. X, x1, x2 vs. X only) comparable?

Comment: How do you want to compare them?

Comment: Say, svm{ y <- X} has an accuracy of 80%, and svm{ y <- X, x1, x2} has an accuracy of 95%. This can mean that x1 and x2 provide additional explanatory power for y.